# Get tommorow's date as a datetime.date object on python

Tags: python, datetime, time

I want to get tommorow's date as datetime.date object just like `"datetime.date.today()"`.
I Need to use `strftime()` on it so timedelta is not an option.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _so timedelta is not an option_  - I think there is some misunderstanding about `timedelta`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
import time
import datetime
cur_tim=time.localtime(time.time() + 24*3600)
datetime.date(cur_tim[0],cur_tim[1],cur_tim[2])
```